# Installing Jenkins on Windows as Service

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to automate build process for Android and iOS apps with the help of Jenkins.

**What I want:**

I am working in secured ODC and installing *Apache Tomcat* will require unnecessary absurd change request process and require chain of approvals. So in order to avoid process block I am trying to deploy Jenkins *.war* as Windows service.

**What I tried:**

- I figured out I need to download `Jenkins` Jar from the [Jenkins web site](https://jenkins.io/)
- Then I followed the [wiki guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service) to run Jenkins as service and run this command

> java -jar C:\Users\663918\Downloads\jenkins.war

**The problem:**

Executing above command giving me the following error. I tried searching on Google but I was unable to find anything useful.

> Error: Could not find or load main class ?jar

If anyone can help me with my situation that would be very helpful.

Comment: So.. this is not related to tomcat at all? Your text is very confusing then. Just leave this fact out.

Comment: removed, StacKOvereflow generated that tag automatically

Answer (score 2):

Try this, opened the registry editor (by typing regedit in cmd) and going to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > jarfile > shell > open > command, then opening (Default) and changing the value from

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*

to

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*

(I just removed the w in javaw.exe.) After that you have to right click a jar -> open with -> choose default program -> navigate to your java folder and open \jre7\bin\java.exe (or any other java.exe file in you java folder). If it doesn't work, try switching to javaw.exe, open a jar file with it, then switch back.

I don't know anything about editing the registry except that it's dangerous, so you might wanna back it up before doing this (in the top bar, File>Export).

Comment: thanks for the clarification that is a hard diff to spot

Answer (score 0):

First line on the wiki:

> NOTE: if you installed Jenkins using the windows installer, you shouldn't need to do anything else here because the windows installer automatically runs Jenkins as a windows service.

Have you used the Windows installer? Otherwise try that one out.

Comment: Installer will require installing software , which requires client approval which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got it working.

In the wiki it is also mentioned that

*Note: Alternatively, you can install a servlet container like GlassFish and Tomcat, which can run as a service by itself, and then deploy Jenkins to it.*

All you have to do is download tomcat (No installation required - you will find binaries. There are some great IDEs available which packages tomcat so that you don't have to worry about setting up at all if you have Eclipse or Spring STS), start tomcat server and then deploy Jenkins.war.

Once it is deployed, you can access Jenkins using URL http://localhost:8080/jenkins/

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the details of the Jenkins service in a file jenkins.xml , located in the same directory as your jenkins.war file.

jenkins.xml :

```
<service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
    <name>Jenkins</name>
     <description>This service runs the Jenkins continuous integration system</description>
      <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="C:\jenkins" />
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx512m-Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8081
            --ajp13Port=8010</arguments>
            </service>
```

After windows service configuration your Jenkins will starts as soon as you start your machine...